# PHP WebSocket Servers

Tags: php, websocket

I want to set up a WebSocket server using PHP. I have many alternatives to do this, yes, but I wanted to ask people who have experienced which one is more reliable (strong, lightweight, and faultless). I also wrote some code, this code creates a socket server, but I'm not sure how to start it, do I need to open the page from the browser?

Comment: You can run socket server with command line

Comment: I guessed that and got a few hears about it, but I don't have ssh access in hosting, how can I execute this command?

Comment: I think we can use exec() command. just my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a web socket server, as many servers, is started to operate as a daemon in the background and listen there for events coming in. On Linux (Ubuntu) you might create a *unit file* to be consumed by the system command *systemctl*, this way the daemon will be started with every boot of the system and you can start and stop it as you need to.
Next you can start it form a command shell like

*nohup php websocketserver &*

This will send your server into the background an stay there until the system is rebooted. Any output is logged to a file named nohup.

On Windows you better create a service, via a schedule task to have your server start at system boot.